# "I did edit my question" or "I edited my question"?

Tags: do-support, emphatic-polarity

If I wrote a question and someone said please edit your question, then I did it and wanted to notice him in comment, which one of these sentences is true for that:

1. I did edit my question
2. I edited my question

Comment: "did edited" is never correct, because after *to do*, we always use the bare infinitive of a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I edited my question.** is the normal way to express this.

**I did edit my question.** would be used in answer to a question, or to emphasize *did* for clarity.